# NIST test vectors for HMAC-SHA-256

Tags: hmac, sha256, nist

I'm working on an implementation of HMAC-SHA-256 in classic ASP (legacy code). I currently have it working, and the resulting values are correct compared to some test cases I came up with along with test cases found in [RFC4231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231). Does NIST have published test vectors for HMAC-SHA-256? And where would I be able to find them if they do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NIST publishes [a lot of test vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/). Including for HMAC (near the end of that page). In the file contained in the [Zip archive](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/mac/hmactestvectors.zip), the vectors for HMAC/SHA-256 ought to be the ones with the parameter "L=32".

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was able to get it implemented without a problem.

Comment: Am I correct to assume the Hmac-Sha256 of L=32 are truncated in these files?